# Make computed property be calculated once in immutable record types

Tags: c#, record, computed-field

I was making an immutable record type with a computed property like this:

```
public record Example
{
    public int A { get; init; }
    public int B { get; init; }
    public int C => A * B;
}
```

Knowing that record field setters are `init` only, the value of `example.C` should never change for the lifespan of an `example` object.

In the example above, the computation behind the `C` property is very trivial, but for types with compute-intensive properties, caching could affect the speed of a program. **Is there a simple way to make the property be calculated only once? Should it not be a default for immutable record types?**

Of course one can abandon the idea of computed properties and do the computation in the constructor:

```
public record Example
{
    public int A { get; init; }
    public int B { get; init; }
    public int C { get; private init; }
    
    public Example(int A, int B)
    {
        C = A * B;
    }
}
```

But is there a way to do it without a constructor?

Comment: You can make `A` and `B` full property, where `C` will be computed. [See more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init).

Comment: Why don't you want a constructor? I think your second code is very clear and understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often use this pattern to lazily initialize expensive values that may or may not ever be referenced.

```
public record Example
{
    private int? _C;
    
    public int A { get; init; }
    public int B { get; init; }
    public int C => _C ??= (A * B);
}
```

Comment: This approach doesn't update C during mutations. Consider the following code: `var ex = new Example { A = 3, B = 4 }; ex = ex with { A = 2 };` After changing A the property C has a wrong value.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaner way:

```
public record Example(int A, int B)
{
    public int C { get; init; } = A * B;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I still recommend using constructor, because code readability and generality. In addition, if the calculation process of the `C` is complicated, define a `private` method.

```
public record Example
{
    public int A { get; init; }
    public int B { get; init; }
    public int C { get; init; }

    public Example(int a, int b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = InitC();
    }
    
    private int InitC()
    {
        return A * B;
    }
}
```